# How to make optional params name in express route?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Here is below my code of route:-

```
app.get('/server/lead/get/:id?', leadCtrl.get);
app.get('/server/lead/filter/:filterQuery', leadCtrl.get);
```

As you see above i am using different route to access same controller method `leadCtrl.get`.

Now, i want something like route `app.get('/server/lead/get/:id?:filter?', leadCtrl.get);`. So, i can get params either `req.params.id` or `req.params.filter` but only one at a time.

Comment: `id` and `filter` are just placeholder names, what they mean is entirely up to you. You might as well call it `:idOrFilter` and use `req.params.idOrFilter` to cover both cases.

Comment: thanks for reply but in my case filter params has json and i handle this in server is slit different i.e, `var query;
    if (req.user.userType == 'super_admin')
        query = {};
    else if (req.user.roleOrder < config.highestRoleOrder) {
        query = { companyId: req.user.companyId, createdBy: req.user._id };
    }
    if (req.params.id) {
        query._id = req.params.id;
    } else if (req.params.filterQuery) {
        _.merge(query, JSON.parse(req.params.filterQuery))
    }
    Lead.find(query)`

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand exactly what you want: you want both `/server/lead/get/:id?` and `/server/lead/get/:filter?` to exist at the same time?

Comment: @robertklep It looks like we have a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) here :)

Comment: @robertklep yes, exactly that what i am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you asked in the question is not possible in the form that you describe it.

> Now, i want something like route
>   app.get('/server/lead/get/:id?:filter?', leadCtrl.get);. So, i can get
>   params either req.params.id or req.params.filter but only one at a
>   time.

Your router would have no way to differentiate those two parameters. If it got a request to `/server/lead/get/X` then what is X? A filter or an ID?

### Your options

You have few solutions here:

1. You can either keep using two routes like you did before.
2. You can use a common parameter for both cases as Robert explained in the comments.
3. Or you can use what seems to me the perfect solution for your use case - named query parameters - just use a route `/server/lead/get` and use query parameters to pass id and the filter.

Example URLs:

- `/server/lead/get?id=xxx`
- `/server/lead/get?filterQuery=xxx`

You will only have to make sure in your handler that only one of those two are set at a time with something like:

```
if (req.query.id && req.query.filterQuery) {
  // respond with error
}
```

You can even mix the two if you have `app.get('/server/lead/get/:id?')` route you can have the id in the route and filterQuery as a query parameter. Now the URLs would be:

- `/server/lead/get/xxx` (for id)
- `/server/lead/get?filterQuery=xxx` (for filter)

For more info see: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

### Better way

If you follow some **REST conventions** then you can use:

- app.get('/server/lead/:id') for **one** object with id (**not** optional)
- app.get('/server/lead') for **a list** of objects (with optional filterQuery passed as a query parameter)

That way you would always know that when you access:

- `/server/lead/xxx` - then it's **one** object with ID = xxx
- `/server/lead` - then it's **a list** of any objects
- `/server/lead?filterQuery=xxx` - then it's **a list** of objects that match the query

If you follow the REST conventions for things like this instead of inventing your own, it would be much easier for you to design the routes and handlers, and it would be much easier for other people to use your system.

You may also want to use **plural** `/server/leads` instead of `/server/lead` which is common with REST. That way it will be more obvious that `leads` is a list and `leads/id` is one of its elements.

For more info see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
- http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html
- https://spring.io/understanding/REST

Answer (score 4):

You have to realize that the following two routes match *exactly* the same:

```
app.get('/server/lead/get/:id?',     leadCtrl.get);
app.get('/server/lead/get/:filter?', leadCtrl.get);
```

Express doesn't care about how you name the placeholders, so any requests for `/server/lead/get/SOMEVALUE` will always match the first (the one with `:id`).

You can add a distinction yourself, by only allowing a parameter to match a particular regular expression. From your code, it looks like `:id` should match MongoDB ObjectId's, so you can create a specific match for those:

```
app.get('/server/lead/get/:id([a-fA-F0-9]{24})?', leadCtrl.get);
```

If `SOMEVALUE` matches an ObjectId, it will call `leadCtrl.get` and populate `req.params.id`. If you also add another router for "the rest", you can also cover the `req.params.filter` case:

```
app.get('/server/lead/get/:filter?', leadCtrl.get);
```

As an aside: you're saying that you're passing JSON to the "filter" routes, in the URL. I would strongly suggest using a `POST` route for that, and post the JSON as request body content.